# Null Space of Parity Check Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields, coding-theory

We know that if $\alpha$ be s a primitive element of $F_q$ where $q$ is a prime power then the null space of the following matrix generates a cyclic code of designed distance $\mu$[[1]](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4595330/). 
$$
G_{\alpha}^{(q,\mu)}=\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & \alpha^1 & \alpha^2 & \cdots & \alpha^{q-2} & 0 \\ 
1 & \alpha^2 & \alpha^4 & \cdots & \alpha^{2(q-2)} & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
1 & \alpha^\mu & \alpha^{2\mu} & \cdots & \alpha^{\mu(q-2)} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Let $q-1=p_1^{t_1}\, p_2^{t_2}\,\cdots\, p_n^{t_n}$ where $p_i$, $1\leq i \leq n$, are prime numbers. 
 Suppose that $\beta_i$,$1\leq i \leq n$, be elements of $F_q$ of order $p_i^{t_i}$.

**My question:** What kind of code the null space of $G_{\beta_i}^{(p_i^{t^i},\mu)}$ generate?

My motivation to ask this question was the section $IV$ of [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/825841/).

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix that you show *does not* generate a *cyclic* code but rather an *extended* cyclic code, and your formula for the designed distance is not quite right.  That being said, the parity-check matrices that you ask about generate shorter extended cyclic codes that can be described as (extended) *nonprimitive* BCH codes.

Comment: You right. Maybe it was better that i removed the last column and asked question. Today i was reading [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6134665/) and I found the matrix that i asked in the question can be used to construct quasi-cyclic low-density parity-check codes(lemma 1 and lemma 2). I would greatly appreciate for your answer, Professor Dilip Sarwate.